# how to get the value of string clicked in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

[image: This is my Database]

> Blockquote
>   I am trying to list all the departments in one activity. On clicking a department i want to list all the courses under that department
>   And this is my code **here I am listing all the departments, on clicking a department I want to display all the courses.
>   I want to display all the courses under that particular department**

```
package com.example.android.finalproject
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import android.widget.*
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.department_view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.department_view.view.*

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 */
class RecyclerViewFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var  ref: DatabaseReference


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_view, container, false)


        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Departments")
        val deptRecyclerView = root.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
        deptRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity!!,RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)

        firebaseData(ref,deptRecyclerView)

        return root
    }

    private fun firebaseData(ref: DatabaseReference, deptRecyclerView: RecyclerView?) {

        val option = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<deptData>()
            .setQuery(ref,deptData::class.java)
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .build()

        val firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<deptData, MyViewHolder>(option) {


                override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
                    val itemView =
                        LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.department_view, parent, false)
                    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
                }



                override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int, model: deptData) {
                    val placeid = getRef(position).key.toString()

                    ref.child(placeid).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                activity,
                                "Error Occurred " + p0.toException(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()

                        }

                        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                            holder.txt_name.setText(model.name)

                        }
                    })

                }


            }
        deptRecyclerView!!.adapter = firebaseRecyclerAdapter
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening()


    }


    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {

        init{

            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                val tempInt = 1
                /*if(myListener != null){
                    if(adapterPosition != androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        myListener!!.onItemClickedFromAdapter(items[adapterPosition])
                    }
                }*/
            }

            itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
                /*if(myListener != null){
                    if(adapterPosition != androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        myListener!!.onItemLongClickedFromAdapter(adapterPosition)
                    }
                }*/
                true
            }
        }
        internal var txt_name: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.department_name)
    }

}
```

Comment: Basically you want to know how to give params to your Fragment right ?

Comment: Yes I want to get the value of department so that I can access only the courses belonging to that department

Answer (score 0):

The following works with a basic `RecyclerView.Adapter`, I did not tested it with a Firebase Adapter. But I tried to adapt it and you might modify it a bit to get it work. Hope it will still help you !

You should create a `RecyclerView.Adapter` in a separate file :

```
// selectedDept is a function you will call when an item is clicked
class DeptAdapter(val selectedDept : (YourDeptClass) -> Unit) : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<deptData, MyViewHolder>(options) {

    // Implement members here

    // Set your ViewHolder as an inner class :
    inner class DeptItemViewHolder(val binding : DeptItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun setData(dept : YourDeptClass) {
            // "invoke" the function you set in the parameters of your Adapter
            binding.yourLayoutYouWantToClickOn.setOnClickListener { selectedDept.invoke(dept) }
        }
    }

}
```

And in your Activity that calls it, create your Adapter as follow :

```
class YourActivity() ... {

    private val deptAdapter = DeptAdapter { selectedDept ->
        // "selectedDept" here is the dept of the item you clicked on.
        // Do what you want with it here.
        println(selectedDept.title)
    }

    override fun onCreate(...) {
        // ...
        yourRecyclerView.adapter = deptAdapter
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: am new to android and dint really follow u

Comment: I suggest you to let Firebase Adapter down for now, and try to understand first how a basic RecyclerView works. This tutorial (https://www.raywenderlich.com/1560485-android-recyclerview-tutorial-with-kotlin) is great.